# Why is the MSBuild task ResolveProjectReferences taking a really long time?

Tags: performance, msbuild, silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a Silverlight 4 solution that takes a really long time to build from both VS2010 and the MSBuild 4 command line.

The solution contains 42 projects, one is a Silverlight application project, one web application project, and the rest are class libraries.

The MSBuild diag summary shows these tasks are taking some considerable time...

```
29891 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                 68 calls
115609 ms  CopySilverlightApplications                1 calls
131547 ms  ValidateXaml                              36 calls
425688 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                  68 calls
634031 ms  Build                                     71 calls
```

The project dependencies are quite well arranged, and the build order looks reasonable. I have all projects compiling into a single output folder, and all referenced have CopyLocal = false.

It appears the worst offender is the ResolveProjectReferences, but why should it be taking so long?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the code analysis enabled on build? If so try to disable it. Had a similar issue. After disabling the code analysis the build run ~5 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

`ResolveProjectReferences` has to build every referenced project.
So it is possible, that some projects build multiple times.

Use file-references and a central build process to eliminate this problem.

[i used this in a project once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972101/overridden-afterbuild-target-in-msbuild-script-is-not-executed/21293163)

we reduced our buildtime from 12 minutes to 3 minutes.