# Overridden AfterBuild target in MSBuild script is not executed

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild

I have a very simple MSBuild script that builds a bunch of .sln files:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- Builds all *.sln files under this repository. -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <SolutionFiles Include="**/*.sln" />
    </ItemGroup>


    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFiles)" Targets="Rebuild" />
    </Target>   

    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <Message Text="After Build" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="AfterRebuild">
        <Message Text="After Rebuild" />
    </Target>   

</Project>
```

The AfterBuild/AfterRebuild targets should do something else, i am just testing them now.

I'd like these targets to fire after every project build, but these are not fired.

Am i doing something wrong?

EDIT: Since each project defines its own AfterBuild target, i guess this way wouldn't really work.
I tried placing the *AfterBuild* and *AfterRebuild* targets in their own file (custom.targets) and running MSBuild with /*p:CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets*=custom.targets. This also did not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

You have to add an `<Import Project="MyCommon.proj" />` in every Project after the `Microsoft.*.targets`.
Because `AfterBuild` is defined in `Microsoft.*.targets`

It's actually documented in every project-file.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and    uncomment it. -->
Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
</Target>
```

import your custom or common targets like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MyBuildRoot)\Common.targets" />
```

you can even overwrite `OutputPath` and `IntermediateOutputPath`.
But they have to be imported before `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`.
Otherwise they will not correctly processed by targets defined in `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`.

### Example

#### Common.props

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile> <!-- disables xml-doc generate -->
  <ProjectRootPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</ProjectRootPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(BuildInOnePlace)!=''">
  <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(ProjectRootPath)obj/<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  <BaseOutputPath>$(ProjectRootPath)bin/<BaseOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(BuildInOnePlace)==''">
  <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj/<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  <BaseOutputPath>bin/<BaseOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)$(Configuration)/</OutputPath>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)$(Configuration)/</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

#### Common.targets

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Message Text="$(ProjectName): $(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

#### SubProject1\SubProject1.csproj

```
...
<Import Project="../Common.props" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="../Common.targets" />
...
```

#### SubProject2\SubProject2.csproj

```
...
<Import Project="../Common.props" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="../Common.targets" />
...
```